# Automatically run the curl for every entry in a text document

Tags: curl, batch-file, windows-scripting

I am trying to eliminate entering each individual choice manually and have the curl read from a text document and run the curl automatically for every choice listed in the document. This is the basic curl I have at the moment that can run for one single manually entered choice.

```
echo AccountNumber to set 
set /p AccNum =

curl -X PATCH http://localhost:3232/docs/AccountNumbers/%AccNum% -d 
"@StateCountyCurl.txt" -w "\n\n"

pause
```

This will prompt the user to enter each individual AccNum and will run the curl based on the data in the StateCountyCurl.txt file. I have another file called AccountNumbers.txt which has all the account numbers in it. I would like to modify this curl statement so that it reads all account numbers one by one and runs the curl without me having to enter each number manually every time. Thank you for your help and suggestions.

I am looking for something like (not sure of the syntax)

```
echo AccountNumber to set 
set /p AccNum = "AccountNumbers.txt" //run for every number in this text doc.

curl -X PATCH http://localhost:3232/docs/AccountNumbers/%AccNum% -d 
"@StateCountyCurl.txt" -w "\n\n"
```

pause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use FOR and FINDSTR:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2* delims=!" %%a IN ('findstr /b /v ^; "AccountNumbers.txt"') DO (
    curl -X PATCH http://localhost:3232/docs/AccountNumbers/%%a -d "@StateCountyCurl.txt" -w "\n\n"
)
```

More on `FINDSTR`: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx

More on `FOR`: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is the "!" delimiter between account numbers in the text document? currently I have them each one in new line. I can easily change that.

Comment: The ! is a delimiter, but you don't actually need the !. The FINDSTR gets each line, passes it to FOR, and FOR will parse each line into it's parts. Since you only have one part, it will be placed into %%a. So, keep each account number on a separate line and just make sure you don't use ! as part of the account number.

Comment: The `findstr` is not necessary. The same result, but faster execution, my be achieved with the simpler `FOR /F %%a IN (AccountNumbers.txt) DO ...`